# How to select only the domain name from the Email using SQL Server Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an email address like **venugopal@yahoo.com,venugopal@gmail.com,venugopal@hotmail.com** etc;
I want the output like **yahoo,gmail,hotmailetc;** only the domain names 
can anyone help me with a SQL Server query.

Comment: You should define what you mean by domain name.

Answer (score 3):

You can get everything after the at-sign by using `stuff()`:

```
select stuff(email, 1, charindex('@', email) , '') as domain
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @DomainNames VARCHAR(8000) 
SELECT @DomainNames = COALESCE(@DomainNames + ',', '') + STUFF(REPLACE(email,'.com',''), 1, charindex('@', REPLACE(email,'.com','')) , '') 
FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME

SELECT @DomainNames
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want :

```
select t.*,
       substring(col, charindex('@', col)+1, len(col)) as domain
from table t;
```

**EDIT :**

If you want only domain name then you can do :

```
select t.*, left(domain, charindex('.', domain) - 1)  as domain
from table t cross apply
     ( values (substring(col, charindex('@', col)+1, len(col))) 
     ) tt(domain);
```

Comment: Need only gmail (domailname) with out '.com'

Comment: @venugopal. . . What if you have a `yahoo.com` or `yahoo.co.in` ?, these are two different domains.

Answer (score 0):

Dubble `stuff`, first remove up until @ and then remove after . and to the end

```
declare @email varchar(100);
set @email = 'venugopal@yahoo.com';

select stuff(domain, charindex('.', domain), len(domain)-1, '') 
from (select stuff(@email, 1, charindex('@', @email) , '') as domain) x
```